# DOM can't read right the opening Tag of a XML file

Tags: magento2, configuration

I work with **Magento ver. 2.1.7** and when I open the admin panel, I get this message after only trying to navigate to (*Stores -> Configuration*)

> Warning: DOMDocument::loadXML(): Start tag expected, '&lt;' not found in Entity, line: 1 in /srv/www/my-project/vendor/magento/module-config/Model/Config/Structure/Reader.php on line 132

I think it means that the `<` is missing from the opening Tag of a XML File after trying to open the Configuration in the Admin-Backend.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: disable custom module after check.

Comment: check system.xml of recently added / modified module